# Однократно добавить обертку блоку при изменении размера окна, если ширина меньше определенной

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть элемент, которому нужно добавить обертку, если ширина меньше 700 пикселей. Попробовал поставить флаг, но что-то не срабатывает, подскажите как исправить

```js
function load() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  m = 0;
  if (m = 0 && w < 700) {
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').wrap("<div class='resp'></div>");
    m++;
  } else {
    m = 0;
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').unwrap("<div class='resp'></div>");
  }
}
$(window).resize(load);
$(document).ready(load);
```

```css
.art-vmenublockcontent {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #f48024;
}
.resp {
  background: #45a163;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class='art-vmenublockcontent'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас ошибка, в первом усовии вы используете оператор присвоения "=" вместо оператора сравнения "==" (я предпочитаю оператор строгого сравнения "===").

```
function load() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  m = 0;
  // m === 0 - операция сравнения переменной m со значением "0"
  if (m === 0 && w < 700) {
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').wrap("<div class='resp'></div>");
    m++;
  } else {
    m = 0;
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').unwrap("<div class='resp'></div>");
  }
}
$(window).resize(load);
$(document).ready(load);
```

Но, ваш код можно упростить, так как использование флага в этом случае избыточно. Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
function load() {
  var browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      respDiv = "<div class='resp'></div>";
  if (browserWidth < 700) {
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').wrap(respDiv);
  } else {
    $('.art-vmenublockcontent').unwrap(respDiv);
  }
}

$(window).resize(load);
$(document).ready(load);
```

Comment: если убрать флаг, то и у меня все работает, но каждый раз при изменении размера окна добавляется еще одна обертка. Вопрос, в том, чтобы добавить ее однократно. Проверьте свой код, в вашем случае wrap добавляется постоянно